# Preserve leading zeros when saving numeric values in database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement, column-types

When executing dynamic MySQL prepared statements to INSERT or UPDATE, leading zeros (such as `0` in `0213123`) disappear. How can I prevent this?

```
public function update($tablo, array $column, array $form)
{
    global $db;
    $sutun = implode(' = ?, ', array_keys($column)) . ' = ?';
    $where = implode(' = ?, ', array_keys($form)) . ' = ?';
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE $tablo SET $sutun  WHERE $where") or die($this->db->error);
    $form = array_merge($column, $form);
    call_user_func_array(array($stmt,'bind_param'), $this->params($form));
    return $stmt->execute() or die($this->db->error);
}

public function params($params, $types = '', $input = array())
{
    foreach ($params as $key => $val) {
        ${$key} = $val;
        $input[] =& ${$key};

        if (is_numeric($val) AND fmod($val, 1) === 0.00) {
            $types .= 'i';
        } elseif (is_float($val)) {
            $types .= 'd';
        } elseif (is_string($val) OR fmod($val, 1) !== 0.00) {
            $types .= 's';
        } else {
            $types .= 'b';
        }
    }
    array_unshift($input, $types);
    return $input;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15625057/php-mysqli-prepared-statements-removing-leading-zeros

Comment: : "It looks like you're writing your own ORM. Have you considered using one that's already written, tested, and widely supported like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent)?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be the behavior of the database. The column is likely a datatype that doesn't allow leading zeros, such as `INT`. Try changing that column to `VARCHAR`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `is_numeric()` to decide whether to use `i` as the type. It will be `true` for a string like `"0213123"`. That will cause it to be parsed as a number, instead of keeping it as a string. Use `is_int()`.

```
    if (is_int($val)) {
        $types .= 'i';
    } elseif (is_float($val)) {
        $types .= 'd';
    } elseif (is_string($val)) {
        $types .= 's';
    } else {
        $types .= 'b';
    }
```

However, this means you won't be able to use numeric strings for integer or float columns. The caller needs to provide the appropriate types.

But that shouldn't be much of a problem. MySQL will automatically convert types when storing into the database, so the types specified in the `prepare()` call don't have to match the database types exactly.